# My GUI doesn't start on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, gpu, amdgpu

I have Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS and after reinstalling my AMD GPU driver my GUI started not to start. My GPU is AMD RADEON RX 6600XT and the first time I installed AMD GPU driver everything worked perfectly but when I wanted to reinstall this driver and install some more things like ROCM, GUI started not to show.

Only thing that works to start GUI is to do `startx` but this doesn't run my GPU driver so better is `sudo modprobe amdgpu` and this works for me to start my GUI and my GPU driver at once but I don't want to run this command everytime I launch my PC, so I tried going to GRUB and adding line `modprobe=amdgpu` but it just didn't help.

If someone knows what I am doing wrong or what I can do better, please tell me.